# How can I prevent ChatGPT from making labelled / definition lists?

Tags: chatgpt, prompt-design

I've noticed that ChatGPT often writes lists with labels like this:

> - Lorem ipsum: dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
> - Ut enim ad minim veniam: quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
> - Duis aute irure: dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
> - Excepteur sint: occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

How can I prevent it or discourage it from doing this? I don't care what other "format" it  writes in as long as it doesn't do this.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used to get an example of labelled list that ChatGPT would normally generates.

> give me some examples of popular games using labels

This is the result.

> Sure! Here are some examples of popular games categorized by their
> genres:
>
> Action/Adventure:
>
> - The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild
> - Assassin's Creed Valhalla
> - Red Dead Redemption 2
> - God of War
> - Spider-Man: Miles Morales
>
> First-Person Shooter (FPS):
>
> - Call of Duty: Warzone
> - Apex Legends
> - Halo Infinite
> - Overwatch
> - Destiny 2
>
> Role-Playing Game (RPG):
>
> - The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
> - Final Fantasy VII Remake
> - Cyberpunk 2077
> - Skyrim
> - Dark Souls III
>
> Sports:
>
> - FIFA 22
> - NBA 2K22
> - Madden NFL 22
> - MLB The Show 21
> - Rocket League
>
> Simulation:
>
> - The Sims 4
> - Animal Crossing: New Horizons
> - Microsoft Flight Simulator
> - Cities: Skylines
> - Euro Truck Simulator 2
>
> Strategy:
>
> - Sid Meier's Civilization VI
> - XCOM 2
> - Total War: Three Kingdoms
> - Crusader Kings III
> - Age of Empires IV
>
> Indie:
>
> - Celeste
> - Hades
> - Hollow Knight
> - Stardew Valley
> - Cuphead
>
> These are just a few examples of popular games across different
> genres. Gaming is a diverse and constantly evolving industry, and
> there are many more games available for players to explore and enjoy!

I adjusted the prompt to make a constraint that I do not want labels.

> give me some examples of popular games without using labels

I still gave me lists.

> Sure! Here are some examples of popular games:
>
> 1. The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild
> 2. Assassin's Creed Valhalla
> 3. Call of Duty: Warzone
> 4. Fortnite
> 5. Minecraft
> 6. Among Us
> 7. FIFA 22
> 8. Apex Legends
> 9. The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt
> 10. Animal Crossing: New Horizons
> 11. Super Mario Bros.
> 12. Red Dead Redemption 2
> 13. Cyberpunk 2077
> 14. Overwatch
> 15. Stardew Valley
> 16. Halo Infinite
> 17. Final Fantasy VII Remake
> 18. Spider-Man: Miles Morales
> 19. Rocket League
> 20. Celeste
>
> These games represent a mix of different genres and have gained
> popularity among players worldwide.

I tried many different combination of prompts that restrict the use of lists and labels but no success. However, I ended up forcing it into 1 paragraph hoping that there will be no lists or labels in the paragraph. This is the prompt.

> give me some examples of popular games in 1 paragraph

This is the result.

> Sure! There are many popular games across various genres that have
> captivated players worldwide. Some examples include "The Legend of
> Zelda: Breath of the Wild," an action-adventure game with an expansive
> open world; "Minecraft," a sandbox game that allows players to build
> and explore infinite blocky worlds; "Fortnite," a fast-paced battle
> royale game with building mechanics; "Among Us," a social deduction
> game where players must uncover impostors in their midst; and "Call of
> Duty: Warzone," a popular first-person shooter game featuring intense
> multiplayer battles. These games, among others, have earned widespread
> acclaim and continue to entertain gamers of all ages.

It no longer generates lists or labels since it is forced to put the information in 1 paragraph. However, it gives less examples but more details in each examples.